# Is there a way to create a combobox in Zend2

Tags: combobox, zend-framework2

I'm using Zend2 and I need a select that allows for input of arbitrary text if none of the selectable items is appropriate.  Zend2 doesn't seem to have a combobox element.  Ideas?

Comment: Please read the documentation : http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.form.elements.html#select

Comment: What you're describing is more like an Input-Field with a DataList attached. DataList currently isn't available in ZF2 tho.